# Avoid collision, if copying files

Tags: linux, bash, file, find, mv

I was trying to copy all files of a certain filetype from all subfolders to one place. Unfortunately, this might cause collisions, if two files have the same name from two different subfolders.

I was using

```
find ./ -name '*.jpg' -exec mv -u '{}' . \;
```

How can I adjust this to automatically rename files (e.g. append "_1") to avoid collisions. 
Or better: check if the files are the same (e.g. same size) beforehand. If yes, ignore (overwrite would be fine, too). If No, rename to avoid collision.

Suggestion would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Rather than exec `mv`, exec `bash -c ' TEST FOR CLASH then mv'`

Answer (score 0):

You could check before moving each individual file. Here I've used `cksum` to compare, which returns both the filesize and a simple checksum.

```
find ./ -name '*.jpg' -print0 |
while read -d '' -r path; do
    file=$(basename "$path")
    if [[ -e $file ]]; then
        if [[ $(cksum "$file" | awk '{print $1 $2}') = $(cksum "$path" | awk '{print $1 $2}') ]]; then
            continue
        fi
        read -n 1 -p "File '$file' would be overwritten by '$path', continue? (y/N) " -r prompt </dev/tty
        if [[ $prompt != [Yy] ]]; then
            continue
        fi
    fi
    mv -f -v "$path" "$file"
done
```

Comment: Can we use `cmp -s` to see if two files are same instead of two `cksum`s?

Comment: @codeforester Absolutely, that would be the better thing to do. I originally wrote `stat -c %s` to demonstrate OP's idea, but that's not portable (it's `stat -f %z` on macOS) so I reached for `cksum` which also outputs size.

Comment: Alright, that helps. But I would also like to have no prompt at all. if they are the same, I don't care if it is overwritten or not (if not, the file to copy should be deleted preferably).
But if the files have a different cksum, it should also automatically be renamed, as I am sure I want to keep both files in this case.